# proposed bug: compiz delay in changing window focus

Tags: compiz

ubuntu-bug really, really seems to want me to ask this as a question on askbuntu.com rather than reporting it as a bug.  So I am.

My machine (for which ubuntu-bug has not attached any details for you, but two salient details are that it's an nv graphics card and 2 x 1920 x 1200 heads) takes roughly a half second to change window focus when I move the mouse to a new window.  This is very long, enough that I have to think to wait.  A reasonable goal in human interface design would be under a tenth of a second.

It's worth noting that I am using sloppy focus mode (focus follows mouse-enter events).

I'm not quite sure how to phrase this as a question, unless the question is "what's the right way to report this as a bug?" or maybe "any suggestions how to tune compiz, and how can we make it so ubuntu users don't have to tune compiz?".

Thanks.

Comment: So to get to sloppy focus you opened ccsm, got to "general options", to "Focus & Raise Behaviour", unmarked "Click to Focus" and marked "Auto Raise"? What did you enter for "Auto Raise Delay"?

Comment: I have FFM set from before things got complicated (i.e., from metacity days).  But running ccsm, I see that auto-raise is unset.  Indeed, I don't want it to auto-raise, so this is good.  While auto-raise delay is (suspiciously) 500, setting it to 10 doesn't change the focus delay.

Comment: I'm having the same problem

Comment: Just ran the first suggestion and the delay, has all but gone. down from half a second to about a tenth of a second. I changed the setting from 500 to 1

Answer (score 0):

That bug is already created at

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/674138

including a rather exhaustive discussion.